# using zsh terminal in vscode not saving commands history

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, zsh

I'm using zsh terminal in vscode on Mac ventura, perviously all commands i use in vscode terminal were saved and can be restored with arrow up/down. but now it is not saved. only the commands i enter in zsh window are saved but in vscode it's not.

for example if i opened zsh terminal window and entered "command 1" and then i opened vscode and click arrow up in the terminal it will show "command 1".
But if i wrote "command 2" in vscode terminal and close and reopen vscode it will still show "command 1" as the latest command

Comment: [Zsh: can I have a combined history for all of my shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/669971/550426). And loosely related: [Zsh: consistent history between machines](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/479592/550426). Related Baeldung for Bash: https://www.baeldung.com/linux/preserve-history-multiple-windows. Related U&L for Bash: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1288/550426 Which one- if any- of those answers your question?

Comment: i'm facing the issue in VS Code integrated terminal. When i try the terminal app the history is saved and restored with no issue, but in vscode terminal the history is restored from terminal app but new commands i write in vscode is not saved when i close and reopen vscode.

Comment: i tried to use bash and i also tried to change the history file where commands are saved but still nothing change

Comment: the $HISTFILE show the path of the history file .zsh_history and $HISTLINES shows nothing

Comment: HISTSIZE is 2000 and HISTCONTROL shows nothing

Comment: See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/151105

Comment: Please always [edit] clarifications into your question post instead of hiding them in the comments! Comments are for _soliciting_ clarifications- not for providing them.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Someone raised an issue on GitHub a few days ago: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/179833

Comment: i have reported the issue on github two weeks ago because it’s seems to be a bug in vscode latest update. And after downgrading to previous version i did not get the issue.